# Transforming a log file that tracks changes with timestamps to a valid-from valid-to type table

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sql-server-2017, change-tracking

I have a kind of log table that I would like to transform using SQL Server - adding a validity interval (valid-from, valid-to fields) to records.

The source table is rather large (100K+ records), so an optimal solution would be required. It is acutally a table that tracks content (status) changes in a field for individual records.

Illustration of the source table:

| RecordId | DateStamp | OldValue | Newvalue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021.01.01. | A Value | Another Value |
| 1 | 2021.02.01 | Another Value | Yet Another Value |
| 1 | 2021.03.01 | Yet Another Value | A Value |
| 1 | 2021.04.01 | A Value | Yet Another Value |
| 4 | 2021.01.01 | B Value | Next Value |
| 4 | 2021.02.01 | Next Value | Second Next Value |
| 4 | 2021.03.01 | Second Next Value | Final Value |

`RecordId` refers to the record on which the field change has been made. `OldValue` and `NewValue` refers to the value of the field before and after the change has been made.

Changes are consecutive. `RecordId` and `OldValue` and `NewValue` fields are arbitrary.

`Value` fields can switch back and forth between statuses.

Definition of the source table:

```
CREATE TABLE Log (
   RecordId INT
  , DateStamp DATE
  , OldValue VARCHAR(255)
  , NewValue VARCHAR(255)
);
```

Example data for table:

```
INSERT INTO Log (RecordId, DateStamp, OldValue, NewValue) VALUES (1, '2021-01-01', 'A Value', 'Another Value');
INSERT INTO Log (RecordId, DateStamp, OldValue, NewValue) VALUES (1, '2021-02-01', 'Another Value', 'Yet Another Value');
INSERT INTO Log (RecordId, DateStamp, OldValue, NewValue) VALUES (1, '2021-03-01', 'Yet Another Value', 'A Value');
INSERT INTO Log (RecordId, DateStamp, OldValue, NewValue) VALUES (1, '2021-04-01', 'A Value', 'Yet Another Value');
INSERT INTO Log (RecordId, DateStamp, OldValue, NewValue) VALUES (4, '2021-01-01', 'B Value', 'Next Value');
INSERT INTO Log (RecordId, DateStamp, OldValue, NewValue) VALUES (4, '2021-02-01', 'Next Value', 'Second Next Value');
INSERT INTO Log (RecordId, DateStamp, OldValue, NewValue) VALUES (4, '2021-03-01', 'Second Next Value', 'Final Value');
```

Illustration of the desired output table with date slicing - so a querying for a status on a given date is possible using the validity dates:

| RecordId | Value | ValidFromDate | ValidToDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A Value | 1900.01.01. (or null) | 2020.12.31. |
| 1 | Another Value | 2021.01.01. | 2021.01.31. |
| 1 | Yet Another Value | 2022.02.01 | 2022.02.28. |
| 1 | A Value | 2022.03.01 | 2022.03.31. |
| 1 | Yet Another Value | 2022.04.01 | 9999.12.31 (or null) |
| 4 | B Value | 1900.01.01 (or null) | 2021.12.31 |
| 4 | Next Value | 2022.01.01 | 2022.01.31. |
| 4 | Second Next Value | 2022.02.01 | 2022.02.28. |
| 4 | Final | 2022.03.01 | 9999.12.31 (or null) |

Is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: If the code in the fiddle is important to your question, please include it in the question itself too; fiddles should complement the question, not be required to view to be able to answer it. When I try to load that link, it fails to load, so I can't see if it's important or not.

Comment: Thank you. It just contains the source table so that one can try a solution.

Comment: So [edit] that into your question, please.

Comment: The fiddle should open okay and I have added the description to the question.

Comment: Don't add a description of the fiddle, add the contents of the fiddle to the question. If the fiddle isn't important to the question, then remove the link.

Comment: I don't know if it is important or not. If I were to answer such a question I would first create a table like the one above and write an SQL which I would then post. And in this case having a CREATE TABLE query would help me. But I am no expert...

Comment: Yes, sample DDL and DML is helpful, so why won't you include it in the question..?

Comment: Not related to answering your question, but I'd recommend using half-open intervals (i.e. "`«begin date» ≤ x < «end date»`") as a general practice. For example, your data says that RecordID 1 changed on 2021.01.01 meaning that it had its old value until it was changed, not the day before that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method would be to unpivot the first row, to get 2 rows for the "old" and "new" value, and then you can use `LEAD` to get the valid to date. You can determine the first row, by using `ROW_NUMBER` in a CTE (or derived table), and use the `WHERE` to only return the 1st row, or the "new" rows:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT RecordId,
           DateStamp,
           OldValue,
           NewValue,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RecordID ORDER BY DateStamp) AS RN
    FROM (VALUES(1,CONVERT(date,'20210101'),'A Value ','Another Value'),
                (1,CONVERT(date,'20210201'),'Another Value ','Yet Another Value'),
                (1,CONVERT(date,'20210301'),'Yet Another Value ','A Value'),
                (1,CONVERT(date,'20210401'),'A Value ','Yet Another Value'),
                (4,CONVERT(date,'20210101'),'B Value ','Next Value'),
                (4,CONVERT(date,'20210201'),'Next Value ','Second Next Value'),
                (4,CONVERT(date,'20210301'),'Second Next Value ','Final Value'))V(RecordId,DateStamp,OldValue,NewValue))
SELECT C.RecordId,
       V.Value AS Value,
       CASE V.ValueType WHEN 'New' THEN C.DateStamp END AS ValidFromDate,
       CASE V.ValueType WHEN 'New' THEN LEAD(DATEADD(DAY, -1, C.DateStamp)) OVER (PARTITION BY C.RecordID ORDER BY C.DateStamp) ELSE  DATEADD(DAY, -1, C.DateStamp) END AS ValidToDate
FROM CTE C
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(C.OldValue, 'Old'),(C.NewValue, 'New'))V(Value,ValueType)
WHERE RN = 1
   OR ValueType = 'New';
```

Answer (score 0):

This code may not be the most efficient or scalable but it works - the part for getting the 'initial' values is what I would be concerned about so other people might have a better suggestion.

The initial query reads data from the table, and it uses the LEAD function to return the date from the 'next' row and then subtract 1 day using the DATEADD to calculate the ValidToDate. I've wrapped it in a CASE statement so that it doesn't read the date for any other RecordID.

The union gets the data for the rows where the ValidFromDate is NULL. It self joins to select only the MIN(DateStamp) and uses DATEADD to subtract a single day for the ValidToDate calculation.

```
SELECT L.RecordId,
       L.NewValue AS [Value],
       L.DateStamp AS ValidFromDate,
       CASE WHEN LEAD(L.RecordId, 1) OVER (ORDER BY L.RecordId, L.DateStamp) = L.RecordId
           THEN DATEADD(DD, -1, LEAD(L.DateStamp, 1) OVER (ORDER BY L.RecordId, L.DateStamp))
           ELSE NULL
       END AS ValidToDate
FROM #Log AS L
UNION ALL
SELECT L.RecordId,
       L.OldValue,
       NULL AS ValidFromDate,
       DATEADD(DD, -1, MinL.DateStamp) AS ValidToDate
FROM #Log AS L
     INNER JOIN (SELECT L.RecordId, MIN(L.DateStamp) AS DateStamp FROM #Log AS L GROUP BY L.RecordId) AS MinL ON MinL.DateStamp = L.DateStamp AND MinL.RecordId = L.RecordId
ORDER BY L.RecordId,
         L.DateStamp;
```